# Read one line from 200gb text file which is stored on azure blob storage using C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, c#-4.0, azure-blob-storage

I have 200 gb text file on azure blob storage . I want to search in the text and then matching line need to download instead of whole 200 gb file and then select that line.

I have written code in c# by downloading complete file and then searching and selecting but its taking too much time and then failed with timeout error .

```
var content ="" ////Downloading whole text from azure blob storage
 StringReader strReader = new StringReader(contents);
 var searchedLines1 = contents.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
            Select((text, index) => new { text, lineNumber = index + 1 })
                       .Where(x => x.text.Contains("TYLER15727@YAHOO.COM") || x.lineNumber == 1);
```

Comment: 200 gig text file in a azure block storage that you need to search.... I feel you need to rethink your design.

Comment: What type is `contents` i am guessing string? How are you storing 200gigs in a string? are you sure this is 200gb and not 200mb?

Comment: Have you tried reading line by line, using `StreamReader.ReadLine

Comment: content is text which is separated by line

Comment: @amethianil something is not adding up here... Also I am finding it hard to believe this is the real code. For starters you are unlikely to ever get 200gbs in a string in .net. Secondly you have a `StringReader` that is doing nothing. Thirdly, neither `StringReader`, or `Split` is ever going to *time out*

Comment: @  00110001 2  Thanks, code is giving timeout while downloading text from blob storage so I need to just read lines direclty from blob instead of downloading 200 gb files

Comment: But if the line you seek is the last line, you'll still need to download 200gbs. Download this file one time, split it and store it back into eg Table storage or DB, something that can search on server. Existing solution is terrible and needs to be thrown away

Comment: You, or someone, has chosen a design that will not perform good no matter what you try. You will have to redesign your storage system so that you have it in a manner more suitable for the problems you want to solve with it. In particular you should split this file into rows in some kind of database, indexed by email address(es) present, at the least, so that this kind of query would run in milliseconds and not minutes/hours.

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous comment. If you keep it as one big 200GB file, you cannot search it for all lines containing a particular email address in a short amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to stream the file and set the timeout. I have wrapped the stream implementation in `IAsyncEnumerable` which is completely unnecessary... but why not

**Given**

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> Read(StreamReader stream)
{
   while(!stream.EndOfStream)
      yield return await stream.ReadLineAsync();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var blobClient = new BlobClient( ... , new BlobClientOptions()
{
   Transport = new HttpClientTransport(new HttpClient {Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan}),
   Retry = {NetworkTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan}
});

await using var stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync();
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

await foreach (var line in Read(reader))
   if (line.Contains("bob"))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Yehaa");
      // exit or what ever
   }
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : Completely untested*</sub>

<sub>***Note** : If you are using C#4 you will need to remove all all the awaits and async methods, and just use the for loop with `stream.ReadLine`*</sub>

Comment: I'd suggest to use this only _once_: To break that abomination of a text file into pieces and create a decent data concept.